# :hover для IEv6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html, javascript, css

В `IEv6` псевдокласс `:hover` поддерживается только для ссылок. Как расширить это свойство на `<td></td>`?

Comment: Вписать ссылку в ячейку.

Comment: Спасибо, но меня интересуют хаки на JavaScript(jQuery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то это не хаки... Используйте `$('td').hover`, если уж так нужно, но я бы лучше использовал `<a/>` (см. [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/))